# Xcode runs code that I deleted

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I deleted large sections of code and Xcode still runs it.

I did the following to try and alleviate the problem:

- Restart Xcode
- Unplug the iPod
- Build: Clean
- Build: Clean all targets

Nothing has changed

Appreciate your help... thanks.

an example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    if (i==4){
        //eventA
    }
    else{
        //eventB
    }
}
```

eventB
eventB
eventB
eventB
eventA

will produce the same result as:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    if (i==777){  <<----------- note the change
        // deleted eventA
    }
    else{
        //eventB
    }
}
```

eventB
eventB
eventB
eventB
eventA

however, I get what is expect here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    if (i==4){ <<----------- placed the 4 back
        // deleted eventA
    }
    else{
        //eventB
    }
}
```

eventB
eventB
eventB
eventB

Comment: Did you delete the app on the iPod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try bounding the conditions more:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    if (i==4){ 
        //eventA
    }
    else if (i < 4){ <<-------bounding the else
        //eventB
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you edited the file you think you did? Perhaps you edited a copy from another folder?

Comment: Very sure since there is only one instance.

Comment: Also I can delete the whole page of code. Run it so nothing works.  Put the code back in and get the same deleted code executing again.

Comment: @Kristen Martinson: And there's no superclass that implements the same method ?

Comment: @DarkDust ... No, I have code within condition statements that were deleted that are executing.

Comment: silly question, but did you rebuild the app after you cleaned and etc?

Comment: What happens if you put a line in that should not compile? Does it still build if you put in, say `NSLog(";`?

Comment: if i force an error, it will catch it.  Remove the error and it still does the same execution of deleted code.

Comment: I have had this happen before and the only way to clear it was to open a new Xcode session and cut and paste.  But that is ridiculous to do after the code reaches a certain size.

Comment: I am beginning to wonder if my computer, not even a year old, is bad. ??

Answer (score 0):

Go to `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` and delete everything inside the directory. In the simulator click `iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings...`. If your code is still getting executed, it is because it is getting compiled again, and there must be a silly mistake somewhere, like you executing the wrong target or something.

Comment: I don't have a "Library/Developer" or anything resembling what comes after.

Comment: Weird. Go to XCode > Preferences > Locations. Right at the top it should say "Derived Data (index, logs, build) Location". There will be a path and a little arrow. Click the little arrow to open Finder on that location. That is the place where XCode builds your application. If you delete the contents, you are left with just your source code.

Comment: Aah yes, that's it then. Well, it won't be long before you migrate to 4 I suppose, next time you know what to do to discard XCode errors. :)